# How do you say "reliable" for cars and telephone systems?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

How do you say that a technological system (like a car or a telephone system) is reliable? E.g. not prone to downtime, robust, starts in the winter every time?

I thought about:

- confiable
- fiable
- ?

Answer (score 4):

*Confiable* sounds a bit odd to me, but it can be a valid option. I am from Spain, and personally I'd prefer ***[fiable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HpsmYNC)***:

> 2. Adj. Que ofrece seguridad o buenos resultados.

You can even say that the system is ***[seguro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XTrgHXd)***:

> 4. Adj. Que no falla o que ofrece confianza.

In this case you must make sure that the chosen word to represent the concept is widely used by your target, and that will depend on the target's country.

Comment: Probablemente hay alguna diferencia regional. En Chile _fiable_ se usaría para confirmar datos (una encuesta, una investigación, una bibliografía). Mientras que un teléfono, un auto o una persona serían _confiables_. Por su parte _seguro_ funciona perfecto.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Rodrigo. Hay diferencias regionales. En Colombia muy pocas personas usan la palabra fiable excepto para hablar de una persona. Es muy común oír que "fulano es de fiar" pero no para objetos para los cuales casi siempre usamos "confiable". Obviamente "fiable" es correcto.

Comment: @Rodrigo sí, soy consciente de ello. Sé que _confiable_ es una opción válida y sobre todo muy usada en Chile, Colombia y muchos otros países. Sí que es cierto que en este caso hay diferencias regionales, por lo que la palabra escogida deberá tener en cuenta el público objetivo.

Comment: Caramba, tuve la misma sensación al leer la respuesta de @DGaleano . Claramente es algo que cambia de un lado al otro del charco.

Answer (score 3):

**Confiable** would be the word I'd use.

> Este teléfono es poco confiable = This phone is unreliable.

And a very Colombian example.

> Mi carro es muy confiable. Nunca se vara. = My car is very reliable. It never breaks.

Comment: @fedorqui that must be a record. My answer was edited 28 seconds after I hit 'post'. :-)

Comment: Haha I was editing the question when I saw your answer come in, so I could not resist editing it : )

Comment: @fedorqui There should be a golden medal for that. :-D

Answer (score 2):

I would say `fiable` or something more informal like `es de fiar`

> ```
> Este coche es de fiar.
> Los sistemas que tiene el coche son de fiar.
> El móvil es de fiar.
> ```